# redirect page after login, join, forgot password or a combination of these

Tags: javascript, html, url, redirect, cookies

I have options to save/share/write on a page, which cannot be done unless they are signed in. Redirecting on click, to sign in page and bringing back can be done using cookies &/or passing URL query parameters (do let me know if there is a better way.

But, what about when the user goes through other pages? 
like: trying to save --> sign in page --> forgot password page -->

I am not allowed to use flyouts. Please let me know the best way..

Comment: Are you using a framework?

Comment: not really. just javascript and jquery based code in .jsp files

Answer (score 0):

You should more completly learn technologies you are using.

Most convient way for all "keep-user-on-site" scenarios is COOKIE.

COOKIE is the only thing (and they are created for it) that live and send TO and FROM server on every page of SITE.

Cookies use DOMAIN based resolution so u can use single cookie not just for all pages of single domain, but for whole domain family.

But "forgot password" is not case of "keep-user-on-site". It's oppsite to this case. It's "we-know-that-it-is-not-user-for-now" - in this situation you always should prefer to use some temporal hashes in URLs that could be treated by your server as trusted.

Never mix them (cookies for long-live and urls for 'not-users'). When "we-know-that-it-is-not-user-for-now" pages are shown - all cookies, session headers and so on should be killed. At other if someone lost password, ask for new key on E-mail and then reset password - it could not cause LOGON operation and enter on site. You should redirect to logon page.